# Why do I receive values from a closed channel?

Tags: concurrency, go

I'm investigating the channels behaviour and I'm quite confused by their behaviour. The spec say `After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been received, receive operations will return the zero value for the channel's type without blocking.` However it seems I still get the values in the range statement even if by that time the channel is closed. Why is that?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "time"

func main() {
    iCh := make(chan int, 99)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                iCh <- i
            }(i)

        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(iCh)
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    print("the channel should be closed by now\n")
    for i := range iCh {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", i)
    }
    print("done")
}
```

**Edit:** It seems that if I move the `close` statement just before the channel range it closes it for good. So I'm wondering why it's not working with the "time.Sleep" trick too . By that time (5 seconds) all the go routines should have been completed and the channel closed, isn't it ?

Comment: You directly quote the documentation that answers your question?? "… **and after** any **previously sent** values have been received…" BTW, I suspect that when you move the close the goroutines panic writing to a closed channel.

Comment: @DaveC the issue was actually that when I tested it I didn't have time.Sleep so basically I just read from a closed channel because the go routines didn't have time to send any value . http://play.golang.org/p/ssBAwu3oXi

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, I’m glad that you found your answer. May I suggest you amend your example to where it was originally broken? Submitting this question with a working example it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Close](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)
>
> For a channel c, the built-in function close(c) records that no more
>   values will be sent on the channel.
>   After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been
>   received, receive operations will return the zero value for the
>   channel's type without blocking.

In the channel buffer there are 5 previously sent values followed by a close.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    iCh := make(chan int, 99)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                iCh <- i
            }(i)

        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(iCh)
    }()

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("previously sent values", len(iCh))
    for i := range iCh {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", i)
    }
    print("the channel should be closed by now\n")
    print("done")
}
```

Output:

```
previously sent values 5
0
1
2
3
4
the channel should be closed by now
done
```