# Faster close of goroutines with channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm new in GO, and I have a question about stopping goroutines with channel signal.

I have a long-running goroutines (more than 1000) and managerto manage it:

```
func myThreadFunc(stop chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <- stop:
            log.Debug("Stopping thread")
            return
        default:
            callClientTask() 
        }
    }
}

func callClientTask() {
    // This can take long time up to 30 seconds - this is external HTTP API call
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}


func manager() {
    var cancelChannelSlice []chan bool
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        cancelChannel := make(chan bool)
        cancelChannelSlice = append(cancelChannelSlice, cancelChannel)

        go myThreadFunc(cancelChannel)
    }

    var stopTest = func() {
        for _, c := range cancelChannelSlice {
            c <- true
        }
    }

    timeout := time.After(time.Duration(300) * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-timeout:
            stopTest()
        default:
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case each time I call `c <- true` manager waits for `callClientTask()` to finish and then go to next `cancelChannel`
I want all goroutines stop in 1 iteration of `callClientTask()` (not more than 30 sec)

Ther only way I tried is to cast new goroutines like this:

```
var stopTest = func() {
        for _, c := range cancelChannelSlice {
            go func(c chan bool) {
                c <- true
                close(c)
            }(c)
        }
    }
```

I this a right way?

Comment: If I understand your requirements correct than neither code is correct: Once c is closed you can read from it. Unfortunately your snippets are too tiny to make real sense, e.g. is stop c ?

Comment: mmm, but I close channel after sending "true" to stopChannel

Comment: Yes the true will be read by `<- stop` but if stop is closed `case <- stop` is _also_ executed. See https://go.dev/play/p/9ViyuIktebZ . But again: your isolated snippets make no real sense to me. I do not understand when you want to actually call callClientTask. And you code contains absolutely nothing that would allow to stop callClientTask, so it all makes no real sense to me.

Comment: Closing a channel [does not prevent reading from it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269960)

Comment: @Volker Sorry for bad description. I changed the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: All "threads" should use the same channel and you broadcast stop by closing it. Never send anything on that channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from your question, "you want all goroutines stop in 1 iteration of callClientTask() (not more than 30 sec)" and workers to run concurrently without synchronization problem.

I reorganized code that run concurrently with wait groups.

**Sample Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(stop <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            log.Println("Stopping thread")
            return
        default:
            callClientTask()
        }
    }
}

func callClientTask() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // simulate a long-running task (for testing purposes)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    stop := make(chan struct{})

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(stop, &wg)
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // allow workers to run for a while
    close(stop)                 // stop all workers, close channel
    wg.Wait()                   // wait for all workers
}
```

**Output:**

```
2023/10/26 10:40:44 Stopping thread
2023/10/26 10:40:44 Stopping thread
....
2023/10/26 10:40:49 Stopping thread
2023/10/26 10:40:49 Stopping thread
```

**EDIT:**

You have to update the worker if u want to stop some of the workers. The following code includes workers with 'stop' and 'stopped' channels, and start/stop functions.

**Sample Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Worker struct {
    stop    chan struct{}
    stopped chan struct{}
}

func NewWorker() *Worker {
    return &Worker{
        stop:    make(chan struct{}),
        stopped: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (w *Worker) Start(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-w.stop:
                log.Println("Stopping thread")
                close(w.stopped)
                return
            default:
                callClientTask()
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (w *Worker) Stop() {
    close(w.stop)
    <-w.stopped
}

func callClientTask() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // simulate a long-running task (for testing purposes)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    workers := make([]*Worker, 1000)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        workers[i] = NewWorker()
        workers[i].Start(&wg)
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // allow workers to run for a while 
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ { // stop  first 100 workers
        workers[i].Stop()
    }  
    for i := 100; i < 1000; i++ { // wait other workers to finish
        workers[i].Stop()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**Output:**

```
2023/10/26 12:51:26 Stopping thread
2023/10/26 12:51:28 Stopping thread
2023/10/26 12:51:30 Stopping thread
....
```

Comment: TY for answer! Is it possible in this case to stop for example 100 workers of 1000?

Comment: No, it (the first code) does not provide a way to selectively stop a subset of the workers. Once you close the stop channel, it will give a signal to all the workers to stop. But I added a second code sample to stop some workers first.

Comment: may I ask another one little question? Why we need 2 channels for 1 worker?

Comment: 1. 'Stop' channel is used to give a signal to the worker to stop its execution. A separate stop channel for each worker allows to stop individual workers.                  
2. 'Stopped' channel is used to indicate that a worker has successfully stopped its execution. It allows us to know when a specific worker has completed its task and it is safely stopped.

Comment: 1) It absolutly clear, TY! 2)Is it possible to avoid creating second channel, for example, by deleting stopped worker from slice?

Comment: Without this 'stopped' channel, it might be challenging to know when a specific worker has terminated, especially when managing multiple workers concurrently.